# Exercise on conditional distribution of a stochastic process to another process

Tags: time-series, self-study, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

How can I find the conditional distribution of a stochastic process to another stochastic process?

Given ${{y}_{t}}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{t}{{{\varepsilon }_{j}}}$ and ${{x}_{t}}=\alpha +\beta {{\varepsilon }_{t}}+{{\eta }_{t}}$ and ${{\varepsilon }_{t}}$ and ${{\eta }_{t}}$ are zero mean independent terms with variance resepctively of 
$\sigma _{\varepsilon }^{2}$ and $\sigma _{\eta }^{2}$. I need to find the conditional distribution of 
${{y}_{t}}|{{x}_{t}}$ but I don't know how to start. I started from the mean...so far I have written only $E[\sum\limits_{j=1}^{t}{{{\varepsilon }_{j}}}|\alpha +\beta {{\varepsilon }_{t}}+{{\eta }_{t}}]$ but I don't think it is the right way to proceed. Can anyone give me a hint on how to set up the problem?

Comment: Do you mean that they are zero-mean independent terms of any distribution, or in particular normal variates?

Comment: A good place to start is with $t=1$.

Comment: Yes, they are normal variates.